# Meteor Serving Large Video File

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I have created an intranet app that displays video in the web browser. I tried putting the video (~1GB) in `/public` so that Meteor could serve it, but somehow the server failed to start and running. When I removed the file, the server can run just fine.

What is the best practice for serving such large files? Is it possible to directly access the file (by providing the local location) instead of serving it first ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and could access the files without any issues.

```
meteor create random_project
mkdir public
cp ~/Desktop/big_1gb_moviefile.mp4 public
meteor
```

If you're putting the file in using `Npm.require('fs');` there may be a hot code reload during when the app is running and causing issues then. It might be worth noting you can't do this in production mode (a hot code reload in production mode replaces the project entirely and the client connects to the new one).

If you're doing this, it may be worth using s3 or a cdn to serve the video files instead.

Comment: the system will be used internally. That is weird, somehow the server cannot run when I add the file. It is mp4 file though. Please see the screenshot I attached in the question. Notice that the first one the server manage to start, but the second it just abort.

Comment: @HaikalNashuha it may be a problem specific to windows. It might be worth opening an issue on it, I don't think the behaviour would be there on a *nix system.

Comment: I think so too. When I tried it with video file less than 100MB it works fine tho.

Comment: do u know how I can run the server in verbose mode or at least where can I find error logs?

Comment: @HaikalNashuha it would be hard to say. Meteor doesn't really have the concept of verbosity, its all shown. The issue is likely with the windows version of the file loader, since its community supported/unoffical you might want to raise the issue on github: https://github.com/sdarnell/meteor. There were various workarounds needed to get the hot code reloads working and this may have been a caveat